# SQL aggregation on the latest output per machine for each time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID  machine     app     output  time
1   1           A       12      1
2   1           B       15      1
3   1           B       8       3
4   1           A       11      4
5   2           C       14      4
6   2           D       17      4
```

For each app I want to get the latest output given up to each point in time, and aggregate these results grouped by machine using AVG

So for the table on top, the data before aggregation should be:

```
time    machine     app     latest
1       1           A       12
1       1           B       15
3       1           A       12
3       1           B       8
4       1           A       11
4       1           B       8
4       2           C       14
4       2           D       17
```

And the aggregated result should be:

```
time    machine     avg
1       1           =(12+15)/2
3       1           =(12+8)/2
4       1           =(11+8)/2
4       2           =(14+17)/2
```

What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: @Aviahu28: Please provide more details. Especially the "data before the aggregation" makes no sense to me. Is it calculated data and if so, how do you calculate it?

Comment: I think You have error in Your 'before aggregation' table: the third row should not be present there.

Comment: @PeterElzinga for every machine there are many times. for every time I want the latest output from every app on that machine. so the "data before aggregation" is actually every app's latest output on this machine for the time. I hope this explanation give a better view on the data and the target

Comment: @DarkAnavger since we want all the latest outputs from all the apps per machine on every time, the latest output for app A on time 3 is still 12 and thats why that row being presented. I put this table to help clarify the problem.

Comment: Oh, so it is not that simple... Please prepare some SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/, then I think I will be able to help You quite fast. :)

Comment: @DarkAnavger http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9319/2 thank you

Comment: I understand that you have 3-1-A, because you have an entry for 3-1 (time 3, machine 1) and you have app A entries 1-1-A and 4-1-A. So you want to show time 3 for machine 1 and assume that app A is running without output at that time. But why do you have 4-1-B, but no 5-1-B? How can you know app B is still running for machine 1 in time 4, but not in time 5? I see nothing indicating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as simple as I thought to be, but I think it works just as You want. I changed time column to ts, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ID int, machine int, app char(1), output int, ts int)
;   
INSERT INTO Table1
    (ID,machine,app,output, ts)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A', 12, 1),
    (2, 1, 'B', 15, 1),
    (3, 1, 'B', 8, 3),
    (4, 1, 'A', 11, 4),
    (5, 2, 'C', 14, 4),
    (6, 2, 'D', 17, 4)
;
```

And here is the query:

```
WITH 
times as
(
    SELECT distinct ts FROM Table1
),
machine_apps as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT machine,app FROM Table1
),
grid as 
(
    SELECT  
        ts,machine,app
    FROM
        times
    CROSS JOIN machine_apps
),
last_outputs as
(
    SELECT 
        g.ts,
        g.app,
        g.machine,
        max(t.ts) as last_time
    FROM
        grid g
    JOIN Table1 t ON (t.app = g.app AND t.machine = g.machine AND t.ts <= g.ts)
    GROUP BY
        g.ts,
        g.app,
        g.machine
)
SELECT 
    l.ts,
    l.machine,
    AVG(t.output) as avg
FROM 
    last_outputs l
LEFT JOIN Table1 t ON (t.app = l.app AND t.machine = l.machine AND t.ts = l.last_time)
GROUP BY
    l.ts,
    l.machine
ORDER BY
    l.ts,
    l.machine
```

Comment: No problem, I like this kind of questions. But, I wloud appreaciate upvote and accepting answer if this help You. ;)